# Load only specific functions from include file

Tags: php, include

My guess is no, but just asking to make sure.

It would be great if I could instead of including a big beats of a file with lots of functions I don't need only load functions I need from it.

Like: Include function_xyz and function_123 from file.php.

**I cant edit the file I am including from its from another software**

Sidequestion: could I unload this functions after? If yes would that make sense memory and performance wise since they are loaded and then unloaded.

Comment: Why don't you just move these two functions in a separate file and then include that file ?

Comment: You can do this if...else logic

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran why I know some "stupid" q like this will come? It's not my code I am including from and I try to avoid duplicating the code and then have to keep up with the updates.

Comment: @Alexender how can I do this with if else logic? Example please.

Comment: No I have not since it not solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to split your file into smaller files with less functions.

Howerver, if you want to keep all your functions inside a big file, 
you can declare your functions inside an if statement :

```
if($shouldIDeclareThisFunction) {
    function myFunc() {
         //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not saying but I can not edit the file I am including from. Also I have to say its a bit annoying that ppl on SO always assume ppl asking questions are stupid. Obviously (well I guess not) I would no bother asking this question if I could structure and edit the code I am including from myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**index.php**

```
<?php

    $checkFlag = true;

    include 'inc.php';
?>
```

**inc.php**

```
<?php

if ($checkFlag == true) {

    function test1() {

    }

    function test2() {

    }

} else {



    function test3() {

    }

}
?>
```

Do like this.